# How to transfer data from a UITableViewCell to another UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

[image: Cell]
[image: New View]

How do I transfer data from my UITableViewCell to a UIViewController through a UINavigationController? As an example, what I want to do is transfer the UITableViewCell label name from the cell to the ViewController's label. If you look at the two pictures, you will see what I mean. Also, on another note, how in general do I transfer data from one view to another? Thanks

Comment: You can either use UITableViewDelegate to implement `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` or use UIViewController method `func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)` to pass data to destination view controller.

Comment: You should be using dynamic injection, the answer listed is a terrible answer, dynamic injection by overloading initializes is the correct way to code this according to best practices in design patterns.

Answer (score 1):

in Receiver view controller

in .h file

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString      *strDataOfCell;

@end
```

here make it strong so stays in memory

in table view delegate method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourViewIdentifer"];
    NSString *strData = [self.yourArrayOfData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // Here Put your code to Get value from data source array , which is loaded in tableview
    vc.strDataOfCell = strData;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't able to do it this way because I was using a separate framework from github, but your example code allowed me to search the correct thing to answer my question. So overall, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can declare properties in the view controller header file you want to transfer.
If you navigate through code. You can assign the label to this view controller in table view didSelectRowAtIndexPath.
If you navigate through storyboard segue. You can assign the label to this view controller in prepareForSegue:sender:.

Comment: Would you be able to give me an example of this in code, such as a quick snippet of how you defined a navigation controller to send the data to a view in the prepareForSegue: method, please? I am still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Code Answer]

The answer to my question resides in the "prepareForSegue" method. It's all about manipulating the sender object to send it's data to the next view controller, and the setting next view controller's data based on the sender. I casted the sender to a custom UITableViewCell, took the cell's title, set a navigation controller's rootview to the view controller that was going to receive the data, and boom, gave it the data.